# AWS and Inbound SSH

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

So I know a lot of people have problems logging into ssh due to the whole public key files and such. I'm trying to figure out how to disable all that so that all that is needed to be sent over is a password as would 'traditionally' be the case. I know it's less secure, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to convert from using pem files over to passwords. Anyone know of any good tutorials (or if this is a duplicate, where I can find the last response) in order to do this? Thanks =)

So I don't know why I'm getting downvoted... I'm asking where to get help. I can show whatever is needed, I just have no idea where to find any of this data. I looked through the AWS documentation I could find and didn't see anything. I did a google search and couldn't find anything on how to port over to a less secure ssh dameon. I know it's probably a stupid question, but I don't even know where to go to find the information and I figured you guys would likely know where to at least point me to look for the proper documentation...

Comment: set a password for the user, set PasswordAuthentication yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, restart ssh. done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three areas the connection could be blocked.

1. The password for the user may not be set.
2. SSH may be configured to not allow password authorization, or to only allow a certain group.
3. PAM (the code which handles most password / account stuff on Linux) may not be configured to do authorization.  (Unlikely, this one is a pain when it bites you).

Get access using the keys (for the initial connection, there's no good way around this).  Once you have root, check /var/log/auth.log.  This is where any diagnostic information will be logged by SSH daemon and PAM.

The settings for the SSH daemon are in the manpage sshd_config.  You're probably looking for PasswordAuthentication, AllowGroups, or possibly UsePAM.  You'll need to restart SSH after this.

NOTE: This is a **phenomenally** bad idea.  Being able to use SSH keys is sysadmin 101, and anyone incapable of doing so is quite likely dangerously unqualified.  This is why you're being downvoted.  I mean no disrespect, but there is simply no acceptable justification for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Jayson =) I know it's a bad idea and I told my boss that. I also told them I am horribly not qualified and that we need a proper sysad, but so far nothing... Hopefully they find someone cause this won't turn out well otherwise. Thanks for the info though. I'll try and use that to figure this out. It's a good jumping off point though =)